# Maze depth first path algorithm using recurssion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, maze

I need an algorithm for finding the shortest path in a maze that will use recursion. It is my understanding that algorithms that use recursion are usually DFS.

I have been looking all over the internet and most results are just Dijkstra's algorithm, which is not recursive. Can someone please provide a pseudo code or point me to the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: There's pseudo code available at the [Wikipedia article on DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode). Both non-recursive and recursive variants.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use recursion? The most simple algorithm for finding the shortest path is *BFS*, not DFS, and it is not recursive. I know of no good and fast general-case shortest path algorithm that uses recursion.

But also note that if your graph (maze) is a *tree*, i.e. has no cycles, then from each vertex to each other there is only one way, and it will be shortest, so DFS will be applicable in this case.